# Count the number of distinct IDs that share the same parent

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to write a query which counts the number of *unique* learner_ids taking part in a conversation stream i.e. sharing the same parent_id (OP).

The columns that I have in the table are:

**comment_id, learner_id, parent_id**

So I need to count the ***unique*** learner_id's that share the same parent_id

If I can just output this to another column that would be a good start.

In xls for a similar query (just counting the comment_id's that shared the same parent_id), I pulled all the parent_id's into a new sheet and used the COUNTIF function but this was very resource heavy and won't work going forward. It also will not count distinct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT learner_id), parent_id
FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY parent_id
```